# (DiscordJs v13) How do I get a list of a voice channel in discord interaction guild

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to get a list of all the voice channels that are on the interaction server to put it on a select menu later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the guild object to list the channels, like so:

```
const { options, guild, member } = interaction;

// if you have not disabled caching 
let channels = guild.channels.cache

// no cache
let channels = await guild.channels.fetch()
```

More info at: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels

Comment: I'm not very good, i get a very big list with a lot of other stuffs, how do i use it to get channels id and name?

Comment: try this: `let channels = await guild.channels.fetch(); channels = channels.map((channel) => channel.id && channel.name)`